# Where can I find the names of currency sub-divisions such as cents, centimes,

Tags: currency, abap

This should be useful for anyone who needs to write out amounts in words in SAP.

I need to convert an amount, e.g. $100.15, into words ("One hundred dollars and fifteen cents"). For the amount, I use function module spell_amount, which gives me "one hundred" and "fifteen". The name of the currency is easily found in table TCURT. Where can I find the name of the currency subdivision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no such table. There are already some discussions about it (e.g at [SCN: Table for currency](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1626871)) and the conclusion is: Make your own table.

If you want to create the table, you may get the name of sub-divisions in the [German Wikipedia-article for ISO 4217](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Aktuell_g.C3.BCltige_W.C3.A4hrungen) (*Untereinheit* means sub-division) or [List of circulating currencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies)