# How to get currency FRACTION name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo

If I know culture, can I know currency name and currency fraction name ?

In case of "en-US", it would be `dollar` & `cent`.

I am trying to avoid creation of mapping in database. I would be amazing if asp.net can provide this information... can it ?

PS: The ultimate goal is - given a `double` like 78.54, I want `seventy eight dollars and fifty four cents`. And I don't want to hard-code `dollars` & `cents` because this is supposed to be culture independent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find the names of currency sub-divisions such as cents, centimes,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151531/where-can-i-find-the-names-of-currency-sub-divisions-such-as-cents-centimes)

Comment: @ssg That question is about SAP my friend

Comment: the answer isn't specific to SAP but it certainly doesn't make this duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net lacks number spell-out and currency fraction names.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void Main() 
{
   RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo("SE"); // Sweden

   Console.Clear();
   Console.WriteLine("Region English Name: . . . {0}", ri.EnglishName);
   Console.WriteLine("Native Name: . . . . . . . {0}", ri.NativeName);
   Console.WriteLine("Currency English Name: . . {0}", ri.CurrencyEnglishName);
   Console.WriteLine("Currency Native Name:. . . {0}", ri.CurrencyNativeName);
   Console.WriteLine("Geographical ID: . . . . . {0}", ri.GeoId);
}
/*
 This code example produces the following results:

 Region English Name: . . . Sweden
 Native Name: . . . . . . . Sverige
 Currency English Name: . . Swedish Krona
 Currency Native Name:. . . Svensk krona
 Geographical ID: . . . . . 221

*/
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.currencynativename.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because OP asks for Fraction (e.g. Cent)